# How access the data from an associative array Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to PHP and codeigniter I have recently written a query in the model which is return as expected. The var_dump of the data array from the controller looks like

`array(1){ 
    ["industry"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["title"]=> string(11) "Recruitment" 
            ["active"]=> string(1) "1" 
        } 
    } 
}`

From the view I have tried using a foreach based on industries but am not getting anywhere when trying to access the arrays length and items. Your experience and guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are have 3 nested arrays, so you will need 3 nested foreach's. I tried to do a sample basing on your var_dump, see:

```
 $array = [
     "industry" => [
         "id" => "1",
         "title"=> "Recruitment",
         "active"=> "1"
      ],
 ];


 foreach ($array as $k) {
    foreach ($k as $k2) {
        foreach ($k2 as $k3=>$v) {
            echo $k3." --> ".$v."<br/>";
        }
    }
 }
```

Let me know if it makes sense.